# Item set similarity for real-time calculation purposes?

Tags: recommender-system, java

I am working on a real-time recommendation engine. At one step, I have a feature that resembles a string-encoded item set, so I took Jaccard on the tokenized string to get a good similarity result. Frankly, Jaccard offers great results, but it takes far too much time on runtime.

My current prototype environment for this is written in Java and I am already using the StringTokenizer to fast transform my string into a token set but the set operations thereafter still take a large amount of time - so my idea was to skip the tokenizing part and work on the string directly, but I am not sure on what metric to count for this puspose.

Anyone have any ideas or experiences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [MinHashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinHash) to get a fast approximate jacard similiarity match for your current item set against a database of existing of item sets.

You might use a few min hashes to find quickly find candidate recommendations, and only do the full jacard computation against only the candidates found via min hashing.